# Passing a function as a parameter in injecting data into SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I wrote a `GetLoan` function:

```
private void GetLoan(RadioButton radiobutton)
{
        if(radiobutton.Checked)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(radiobutton.Text);
        }
}
```

and in order to get the necessary data from the radio button I did this,

```
bookCom = new SqlCommand("UPDATE d_Book SET ISBN = @isbn, Author = @author, Title = @title, Publisher = @publisher, Date = @date, Loan = @loan WHERE ISBN = @isbn ", bookCon);

String ISBN = textISBN.Text;
String Author = textAuthor.Text;
String Title = textTitle.Text;
String Publisher = textPublisher.Text;
String Date = textDate.Text;

GetLoan(rdbtn_Yes); // worked fine
GetLoan(rdbtn_No);  // worked fine

bookCom.Connection = bookCon;
bookCon.Open();

if (bookCon.State == ConnectionState.Open)
{
    bookCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isbn", ISBN);
    bookCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@author", Author);
    bookCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", Title);
    bookCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@publisher", Publisher);
    bookCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", Date);
    bookCom.Parameters.Add("@loan", SqlDbType.Char).Value = GetLoan; // didn't work at all
}
```

Is there any way I could get `GetLoan` to work?

Comment: Are you sure that it is possible at all?

Comment: Do you want to show an input box for the user to get the loan amount? cause your code now does nothing but showing the text of the radio button and it will not compile because you are passing the method `GetLoan` as a variable not as a function

Comment: Yes, I already have the input box, what i want is to use my Yes/No radiobuttons to be saved as char or maybe as a string to my Sql Connection @HaithamShaddad

Comment: void return - you are not returning anything from the function.  Looks like you want a 'Y'  'N' logic in the function to return a char.  Make sure the parameter type is really a char and not varchar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify the return type in the function:

```
    private string GetLoan(RadioButton radiobutton)
    {
        if (radiobutton.Checked)
        {
            return "yes";
        }
        else
        {
            return "no";
        }
    }
```

Or as a bool in one line of code:

```
    private bool GetLoan(RadioButton radiobutton)
    {
        return radiobutton.Checked;
    }
```

And then you always need to pass `RadioButton` as a parameter. So change

```
bookCom.Parameters.Add("@loan", SqlDbType.Char).Value = GetLoan;
```

To

```
bookCom.Parameters.Add("@loan", SqlDbType.Char).Value = GetLoan(rdbtn_Yes);
```

But why not make it easier and just check which one is selected:

```
String Loan = "no";
if (rdbtn_Yes.Checked == true)
{
    Loan = "yes";
}
bookCom.Parameters.Add("@loan", SqlDbType.Char).Value = Loan;
```

Answer (score 0):

By reading the snippet provided, I understand that you need to ask user if he/she is interested in loan.
Instead of radio buttons for yes or no, you could consider using a check box then use the below function.

```
private string GetLoan(CheckBox chkBxGetLoan)
{
    //returns string value as output.
    return chkBxGetLoan.Checked ? "Y" : "N";
}
```

OR

```
private char GetLoan(CheckBox chkBxGetLoan)
{
    //returns char value as output.
    return chkBxGetLoan.Checked ? 'Y' : 'N';
}
```